# Plotting a ggplot2 graph in a power point slide with a given size - R

Tags: r, ggplot2, powerpoint, officer

I'm trying to plot a `ggplot2` graph in a power point slide with the `officer` package. I can do it actually (printing the `ggplot2` directly in the ppt), but as I need to increase the size of the `ggplot2` graph (for the ppt slide), and I have understood that `ggplot2` graphs are dependent on the size of the window (in `RStudio`) or whatever you set it as if you are exporting it, I'm looking for a way to (1) export the ggplot2 graph with a given size (for example: `height=5, width=8`), (2) importing/reading from the ppt code:

```
library(officer)
library(devEMF)
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)

t <- "../example.pptx"
filename <- gg

read_pptx() %>% 
  add_slide(layout = "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme") %>% 
  ph_with_img(src = filename, width = 6, height = 4, type = "body") %>% 
  print(target = t)
```

`gg` is any plot from ggplot2 (it doesn't matter actually). `t` is the output file address.

[ph_with_img](https://davidgohel.github.io/officer/reference/ph_with_img.html)

[PowerPoint documents and graphics](https://davidgohel.github.io/officer/articles/offcran/graphics.html)

PD: All of this is unnecesary if there is some package/command I don't know and I still can't find, where I can edit the size of the ggplot2.

Comment: solution to (1): Use e.g. `png()` with `width = 8, height = 5`

Comment: See my answer using the graph2ppt command from the export package, which allows you to specific the width & height...

Comment: No need to externally save ggplot object or use external packages, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had success first saving the `ggplot2` graph as a .png and then calling that file into `ph_with_img`. A bit roundabout, but it works. You can also save the graph as a `?tempfile` and then `?unlink`, but I somewhat like having a folder of my graphs.

```
ggplot() +
  (code for my ggplot)

ggsave("../thisplot.png", width = 6, height = 4)

read_pptx() %>% 
  add_slide(layout = "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme") %>% 
  ph_with_img(src = "../thisplot.png", width = 6, height = 4, type = "body") %>% 
  print(target = t)
```

Comment: Disadvantage of this solution is that the output is bitmap then as opposed to vector graphics... I posted alt answer below which retains vector format...

Answer (score 5):

I just made a new package `export` built on top of `officer` that easily allows one to to do this using the command `graph2ppt()` and which nicely exports in vector format as opposed to bitmap in the other answer posted above, e.g.

```
install.packages("export")
library(export)
library(ggplot2)
qplot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, data = iris, color = Species, 
      size = Petal.Width, alpha = I(0.7))     
graph2ppt(file="plots.pptx", width=6, height=5)
```

Comment: Can this approach be combined with the standard officer language = e.g. `doc <- read_pptx(); doc <- ph_with(x = doc, value = my_ggplot, location = ph_location_fullsize() )` - or is it a full wrapper that only renders a single graphic as a pptx page?

Comment: It's ony a wrapper, internally using officer, and so my only aim was to be able to easily export a single graph, though it also allows adding extra graphs to an existing file.

Answer (score 3):

The following shows how to create and export a ggplot object as a vector graphic directly to powerpoint using `officer 0.3.11`. The key is to use `ph_with` with `location = ph_location`. This allows you to set the position and size of the object.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(officer)
library(rvg)

t <- "example.pptx"

fig_gg <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) +
  geom_point()

fig_vg <- dml(ggobj = fig_gg)

read_pptx() %>% 
  add_slide(layout = "Title Only", master = "Office Theme") %>% 
  ph_with(fig_vg, location = ph_location(left = .5, top = 1.3, height = 5, width = 5)) %>% 
  print(t)
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken this does not change the size (resolution) of the graph but rather the specification of its bounding box on the page.  It gives no control over how big text and margins render.

Comment: @geotheory In my example changing the specs for `width` and `height` do change the size of the figure in powerpoint. Vector images do not have a resolution per se (as compared to raster/bitmap images).  The size of text and margins is controlled from within the ggplot call, eg. `fig_gg + theme(text = element_text(size=20))`.

Comment: It's very fiddly to get all this right inside ggplot. You need a method to re-scale the final plot.

Comment: @geotheory I guess that is a matter of opinion. Setting the options from within the ggplot call ensures the figure is consistent regardless of the output (latex, html, or pptx). I prefer using vector graphics in pptx as it maintains the figure at the highest possible 'resolution', meets journal requirements, allows coworkers to view the image without specialist graphical software, and the final plot is editable from within powerpoint if you still want to tweak font sizes etc.

Comment: Certainly vector is preferable. The reason for my view is that inside ggplot you can either set all text elements to same size (rarely desirable) or individually write _theme_ arguments for each element.  And then repeat for various types of margin/strip/etc.  Or you can just specify adjust `w={x}, h={y}` in ggsave and you're sorted.  Unfortunate that something closer to the latter approach isn't available here.

Comment: Apologies I don't intend to sound critical. I just hate having to faff around with theme!

Comment: Fair enough :) You can adjust the relative size of all text using the `theme(base_size = 20)` argument. See https://community.rstudio.com/t/ggplot-theme-with-larger-font-sizes/30084 for more info.

Comment: I didnt know that! Thanks